# How to apply patches in git when multiple patches has some common changes?

Tags: git, merge, diff, patch, git-patch

Basically, I've created patch for legacy software. In which there is cli fetch, so while doing cli changes, I need to made some changes in service as well. And also, while doing service patch from fresh repo, I've made changes and some of the changes are already done in the previous cli patch.
So, when I'm trying to apply service patch after cli patch, I got the following error:

```bash
git apply service.patch
error: patch failed: service/auth/auth.java:8
error: service/auth/auth.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: service/config/utils.java:4
error: service/config/utils.java: patch does not apply
```

Although, both file has same changes, still it give above error. I couldn't  see the conflict in the file, so I can resolve it. Any suggetion.
By the way I've created the patch using following way:
Step 1: Made changes and staged it using git add .
Step 2: git diff --cached > service.patch

I've check the difference if there any conflict in the both patches, but I found there is no conflict.

Comment: git-apply(1) is a low-level command which doesn’t give useful error messages IME (like just “does not apply”). I seem to recall using git-am(1) for this but now (in testing that) it seems that I can’t use a plain patch format with it...

Comment: Plain `git apply` cannot know that a change that it wants to apply is already applied. Did you try `git apply -3 service.patch`?

Comment: @j6t When I use git apply -3 as you mentioned, the files which do not have any common changes applied but got the following error in files who has common changes. error: service/auth/auth.java: does not match index

Comment: "Does not match index" means that the file has edits that you have not yet staged. Stage them and try again.

Comment: You are much better of by having the changes in `service.patch` on a branch rather than a loose file. With a branch you can rebase on top of new changes with git helping you resolving conflicts because it can track the common ancestor (and I recommend [using kdiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) as a merge tool).